# How to populate data related to an item from the location which is same for all items in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am developing an xamarin.forms app ,I have various fields like Item Name ,Item Number and location ,here Location of all the items are same ,by entering names or number of the items the values are generated automatically because name and number are unique but since the location number is common is for all the items I am not able to populate correct data related to a particular field  ,I am using sqlite database in my project can anyone please suggest me on what basis can I generate related values ?
Here is the code

```
 public async void OnSearch_Location(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (location.Text == string.Empty || location.Text == null)
        {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new ListValuePage("Location", filePath, 
     pos, list));
       }
        else
        {
            for (int p = 0; p < list.Count; p++)
            {
                if (list.ElementAt(p).Aisle + "." + list.ElementAt(p).Bin + 
    "." + list.ElementAt(p).Level == location.Text)
                {
                    line.Text = 
     Convert.ToString(list.ElementAt(p).Line_Number);
                    location.Text = list.ElementAt(p).Aisle + "." + 
    list.ElementAt(p).Bin + "." + list.ElementAt(p).Level;
                   item.Text = list.ElementAt(p).Item_Number;
                    name.Text = list.ElementAt(p).Name;
                   if (list.ElementAt(p).Order_Qty == 0)
                    {
                        order_uom.Text = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        order_qty.Text = 
   Convert.ToString(list.ElementAt(p).Order_Qty);
                    }

                    order_uom.Text = list.ElementAt(p).Order_UOM;
                    if (list.ElementAt(p).Consumption_UOM == string.Empty || 
    list.ElementAt(p).Consumption_UOM == null)
                    {
                       consume_lbl.IsVisible = false;
                        consume_qty.IsVisible = false;
                        consume_uom.IsVisible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        consume_lbl.IsVisible = true;
                        consume_qty.IsVisible = true;
                        consume_uom.IsVisible = true;
                        if (list.ElementAt(p).Consumption_Qty == 0)
                        {
                            consume_qty.Text = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            consume_qty.Text = 
     Convert.ToString(list.ElementAt(p).Consumption_Qty);
                        }

                       consume_uom.Text = list.ElementAt(p).Consumption_UOM;
       }
       }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code.  Your description of the problem is incomprehensible.

Comment: Just added the code ,please find the code in the above post thanks